# exception handling if db connection string is invalid

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

trying to test error condition of not being connected to my db by having an invalid db connection. When i run my app, i get this in the IDE

```
Exception in thread "main" play.exceptions.DatabaseException: Cannot connected to the database, Communications link failure
```

I have following

```
@Before
static void initFromDB()
{
    try{
        //Get some values from DB
       }catch (Exception ex)
       {
           Logger.fatal(ex.toString(), new Object());
           error("Database issue");
       }
}
```

If i launch my site in IE then i get

```
Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage
```

I do not get the 500 page.

I am running in `DEV` mode with `playframework 1.2.4`

In `PROD`, I would not get the error page as it cannot start with errors in prod mode, or so says the message in my IDE

UPDATE 1:
I ensured all my db connections were valid. Switched to `prod` mode. Launched my site, while site is loading, i disconnected from my network and i get a generic error message

```
Oops, an error occured
```

Answer (score 0):

If the DB connection fails the server initialization fails so you won't get your applications' 500 page, but a default one (as per browser) as the server won't be running.